# Update a value in all tables in the entire database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I want to update (change) a value in all tables in the database.

For example:

I have 3 tables

```
tbl_1
tbl_2
tbl_3
```

and I have a string "test" that is used in these tables.
How can I change "test" to "hello" in all 3 tables?

Comment: Seems like a problem caused by a poor table design. Fix that instead!

Comment: you should include the column name of these table also.

Answer (score 1):

you have to update individual table like  below

```
 update tbl_1 
     set col='hello'
    where tbl_1.col='test';

go

update tbl_1 
 set col='hello'
where tbl_1.col='test';
go
update tbl_1 
 set col='hello'
where tbl_1.col='test'
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it easier, you could generate the "updated statement" using information_schema.tables as follows

```
select 'update '+table_name+' a set col=''hello'' where a.col=''test'';'
  from information_schema.tables
where table_name in ('tbl_1','tbl_2',....)
```

Comment: and? what happens after that?

Comment: The result of the query would be update statements which can be run.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it Manually by taking and updating each table and each column like this

```
UPDATE <TableName> SET <Column Name> = <Your New Value> WHERE <Column Name> = <Old Value>
```

Sample :

```
UPDATE Table1 SET COl1 = 'Hello' WHERE Col1 = 'test'
```

Or else you can dynamically do the same by Looping for each Column.

Like this

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Min INT,@Max INT
DECLARE @ColumnList TABLE
(
    SeqNo INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    TableName VARCHAR(500),
    ColumnName VARCHAR(500)
)

INSERT INTO @ColumnList
(
    TableName,
    ColumnName
)
SELECT
    TABLE_NAME,
    COLUMN_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE DATA_TYPE = 'varchar'

SELECT
    @Min = MIN(SeqNo),
    @Max = MAX(SeqNo)
    FROM @ColumnList

WHILE ISNULL(@MIn,0)<=ISNULL(@Max,0)
BEGIN

    SELECT
        @SQL = 'UPDATE ['+LTRIM(RTRIM(TableName))+'] 
                    SET ['+LTRIM(RTRIM(TableName))+'] = ''Hello''
                    WHERE ['+LTRIM(RTRIM(TableName))+'] = ''Test''
                    GO'
        FROM @ColumnList
            WHERE SeqNo = @Min

    EXEC(@SQL)

    SELECT
        @Min = ISNULL(@Min,0)+1

END
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a stored procedure, to update three table, but all of them need to update individually once at a time:

```
   Create Proc Test(@Value Type)
   As
   Begin
      Update dbo.TableName1
      Set ColumnName = @Value Where ColumnName = 'Test'

      Update dbo.TableName2
      Set ColumnName = @Value  Where ColumnName = 'Test'

      Update dbo.TableName2
      Set ColumnName = @Value  Where ColumnName = 'Test'
   End
```